# Cron job using App Engine Cron Service: every day at a given time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cron, terraform

I am trying to deploy a Scheduling Query (BigQuery) using Terraform. I would like to have my Scheduling Query to run every day at 3 am. Scheduling Queries is using the App Engine Cron Service.

The [example provided by Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_data_transfer_config) has a schedule job included in the example. This works for me.

```
 schedule               = "first sunday of quarter 00:00"
```

However, I am trying to run my Scheduling query every day at 3:00 am. What I tried is:
"`every 24h at 03:00`" and then "`every 24h from 03:00`" but none of those worked

Based on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs), `Data transfer schedule...Examples of valid format: 1st,3rd monday of month 15:30, every wed,fri of jan,jun 13:15, and first sunday of quarter 00:00. See more explanation about the format here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#the_schedule_format NOTE: the granularity should be at least 8 hours, or less frequent.`

**my code: main.tf**

```
resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {

  for_each               = local.jobs

  display_name           = each.value.display_name
  data_source_id         = each.value.data_source_id
  schedule               = "every 24h at 03:00"
  destination_dataset_id = each.value.destination_dataset_id
  params = {
    destination_table_name_template = each.value.destination_table_name_template
    write_disposition               = each.value.write_disposition
    query                           = file("scheduling_queries/sql_repo/${each.value.display_name}.sql")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it after a couple of failures: `every day 03:15`